# Django view not redirecting after AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, django, post

I've switched from sending data from a `<form>` to building a JSON string myself and sending that to the server.

I was expecting that after sending a `POST` request to my view that the browser would render the JSON response -- basically, show me a page of the posted JSON data. That was the case when I submitting via a form POST request.

What actually happens is that the browser doesn't do anything. But I can nevertheless see that the server is sending the right response to the browser. But why doesn't the page redirect to show the JSON data?

`javascript.js`

```
async function submit() {

  let response = await fetch('/cartography/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({test: "test"}),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "X-CSRFToken" : csrfToken.value,
    },
  })
}
```

`views.py`

```
def cartography_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_data = json.loads(request.body)
        json_data = json_dumps(request_data)
        return JsonResponse(json_data) # <-- doesn't redirect. but why?
```

`urls.py`

```
path('cartography/', cartography_view, name = 'cartography'),
```

`home.html`

```
<button class="pushable" onclick="submit"/>submit to cartography</button>
```

Edit: this is the response:

```
Response { type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cartography/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your returning json from your view, I would receive it in your Javascript at success and print to console to make sure it's coming back.

Essentially you still need to do something with the request. I normally do this with an Ajax request and on success, receive the return data and display it, show it in alert or pop-up or refresh the page.